# How to check electric kettle using Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

I wanted to measure time it takes to boil fresh cold water and I hoped wolfram would cut me some slack and count the target time for me... But it does not.

I tried "boiling time water 2L 15C with 2000kW heating" - Wolfram tells me water boils at 100C

I tried "heating time water 2L from 15C to boiling with 2000kW heating input" - Wolfram takes it as integer constant 2000

I kind of lost, it seems to be such a simple question for such a sophisticated thing Wolfram is....

Comment: +1 as soon as I read "Wolfram tells me water boils at 100C"

Comment: There is a lot that Alpha can't do yet, https://twitter.com/wacnt (also, I start working at alpha in June!!!)

Comment: Great news, but... well, if you do perhaps you can tell how can one make Wolfram understand such a simple request?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [off-topic because it is purely about Wolfram|Alpha and unrelated to Mathematica](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/265/12).

Comment: Try http://community.wolfram.com/ for W|A questions.

Comment: @JasonB - if you have twitter - post it there plz. I do not